# Fatal error NullPointerException on device rotation android

Tags: android, android-orientation

Although for a phone I will use the same layout regardless of orientation, for a tablet I have one layout for portrait and one for landscape, so ignoring configuration changes is not the optimal solution.

Things become more complicated when the scenario is like this-

1. On **Landscape orientation**, clicked the tab 1 that showed the `fragment 1 (left side)` and `fragment 2 (right side)`. The `fragment 2` contains `button 1`.
2. Then clicked the `button 1` that opened the `dialog fragment (right side)` while `tab 1` with `fragment 1 (left side)` and `fragment 2 (right side)` still in opened state.
3. Rotated the device to **portrait orientation** and application crashed.

The intent is to open only the dialog fragment (which was opened in landscape) in portrait.

Run debugger which ran all the required methods. This doesn't reveal that where is the `NullPointerException`.

The stack trace is not pointing exact method of error -

```
    fatal error : null
    java.lang.NullPointerException?    
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1419)?    
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)?    
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)?    
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)?    
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)?    
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4953)?    
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)?    
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)?    
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)?    
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)?    
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any way ?

Comment: 4.7K and no code in question !!! :P

Comment: @Kedarnath - I can tell you that real problem is it is difficult to figure out the exact code causing problem. So any idea regarding exception or where the problem is can be fine. See scenario.

Comment: How are you handling config changes?  Do you allow the OS to destroy/recreate the activity or are you handling the config changes yourself?  Please show the relevant pieces of your manifest and (if appropriate) the code in `onConfigurationChanged`

Comment: You should observe this, When this error occurs , in which activity you are ? You should check that activity's code.

Comment: @Kedarnath That's about as helpful as a flying whale.

Comment: @AleksG, yOU CAN cONSIDER iT aS fIRST sTEP oF dEBUGGING.

Comment: @Kedarnath Can you please sort out your caps lock issues?

Comment: The problem is that the error trace is not helpful. It only says that there was a null pointer exception. You need to post the part that says "caused by: ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help someone who may face a similar error:

After performing a series of test cases to find out the root cause of this crash, finally it was one line in the code that was the culprit.

And the line was -

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();  
    tap.getEntriesByRule(view); // Culprit
}
```

**Explanation:**

The problem with this line is----

IT MESSED UP THE PENDING TRANSACTION.

While you are at fragment `fragNoPop` and when you rotate the device, you goes to fragment `fragPop`.

In fragPop, we have a culprit onDestroy() which again redirects to `fragNoPop`  with a call to `tap.getEntriesByRule(view);`  which is already destroyed on rotation. So now it is attached again causing a mess.

One line was enough for causing errors like `execPendingActions`.

So first check such activity methods before anything else. Beware!